# Meshlabserver error: unable to save when editing mesh in the commandline

Tags: windows, command-line, 3d, rendering, meshlab

I am trying to edit a mesh in MeshLab through the command line and am using meshlab server through windows10 cmd:

```
meshlabserver -i inputfile.obj -o outputfile.stl
```

Basically what happens is that the output file is unable to save for some reason. The error is as follows (After it says that loading in the input and the conversion both work):

```
Failed Saving
Output mesh :C/Program Files/VCG/MeshLab/outputfile.stl has NOT been saved
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked if you have permission to write in that folder?

Comment: yeah, that was the issue. I was not in administrator mode.